# Copying text from a dataframe with the rclipButton in Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, clipboard

I have a shiny app with a numeric input that controls the number of ColourPickers and rclipButtons that pop up. The buttons turn to be the same color as what is chosen via the ColourPicker.
What I want to do is set the color of each ColourPicker to be a different color, and when I click on the buttons, the hex code from the ColourPicker is copied to my clipboard (as shown):
[image]

I want to be able to paste that hex code into the 'Paste here' box. The problem that I am having is that the code as I have it will only allow me to copy the hex code from the first box. Nothing is copied if I click on the other boxes. If I change the color for button 1, and click on it, then a new corresponding color is copied and can be pasted.

Right now I have it set up (or am trying to at least) so that the hex codes from each ColourPicker is also input into a data.frame, and the data.frame is read by the rclipButtons that match the correct index to know what hex codes to copy.

I think the issue is that the data.frame is not growing with the increasing numbers from my numeric input, but I don't know why. Can someone please help? Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(sortable)
library(colourpicker)
library(glue)
library(png)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(rclipboard)



ui <- fluidPage(
  rclipboardSetup(),
  
  numericInput("num_conds", 
               label = h3("Enter the number of treatments/ conditions"),
               min = 1,
               max = 20,
               value = 1),  
  
  uiOutput("cond_colors"),
  
  htmlOutput("cond_buttons", align = 'center'),
  
  # UI ouputs for the copy-to-clipboard buttons
  uiOutput("clip"),
  
  # A text input for testing the clipboard content.
  textInput("paste", "Paste here:")
  
)



server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  #####Number output for number of conditions#####
  output$value = renderPrint({ input$num_conds })
  
  
  #### Color selection for UI input####
  output$cond_colors <- renderUI({
    num_conds <- as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      colourInput(paste0("colors", i),
                  label = (paste0("Select a color for condition ", i)),
                  show = c("both"),
                  value = "black",
                  palette = c("limited"),
      )
    })
  })
  
  #### Create action buttons for conditions to be selected####
  output$cond_buttons <- renderUI({
    num_conds = as.integer(input$num_conds)
    
    lapply(1:num_conds, function(i) {
      
      bg = input[[paste0("colors", i)]]
      style = paste0(
        collapse = " ",
        glue("background-color:{bg};
                  color:#ffffff;
                  border-color:#000000")
      )
      
      label = input[[paste0("condID", i)]]
      
      hex_df = data.frame(input[[paste0('colors', i)]])
      
      
      cond_buttons = rclipButton(paste0("cond_buttons", i),
                                 label = label,
                                 style = style,
                                 clipText = hex_df[1,i],
                                 icon = NULL)
      
    })
  })
}
  
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix is to just drop `hex_df` completely, and change the `clipText` parameter:

```
clipText = input[[paste0('colors', i)]]
```

Comment: Hmmm... I dunno that seems a little too efficient. Haha yeah, that's a facepalm moment, considering I was using that in the code...